# Windows XAMPP catch all PHP mail() in one local mailbox or folder

Tags: php, windows, wordpress, xampp, mail-server

Using XAMPP on Windows I am developing a WordPress site and need to catch all outgoing emails into a single local mailbox or even a folder. I am testing a plugin that sends out emails, it would be easier to do this locally rather than updating the remote Linux server on every small change.

Any advice on the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use [mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/) for this

Check http://block81.com/articles/test-emails-locally-with-mailcatcher for a tutorial

Comment: That looks absolutely excellent. Glad you spotted my question.